# Filtering or sorting causes page to reload

Tags: asp.net

Applying sorting or filters on the ASPXGridview causes the page to refresh. How can I prevent this? This is kind of annoying to the users.
The enablecallback property for the ASPXGrid is set to false.(I want it to be false).
Also that causes all the user selection to go away(checkboxes,radiobutton defaults to the original)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the gridview inside of an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Well that works for sorting but now my filtering options have disappeared

Comment: Let me rephrase it..I have a label along with my grid.So if there is any exception thrown while inserting or editing the data on the grid. I display the appropriate message on this label. After adding the grid on the update panel I am getting the behavior I want but now my label never displays the message. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Put the label in the UpdatePanel too.